# forecast() and naive() returns NA for forecast$fitted and naive$fitted. What does it mean?

Tags: r, na, forecast

I'm building a naive model and a neural network model which then I use smape() to check for the error. smape() returns NA.

I traced the values that I put in smape() [smape command and result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hJIlX.png)and figured it might be because my naive() and forecast() returns naive$fitted and forecast$fitted values starting with an NA or some NAs. I don't know why the model returns NA [naive$fitted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iz4vO.png), [forecast$fitted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vfZtE.png).[naive command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/icK1v.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.